# Remove the quotations from Object Array in JavaScript to pass as parameter to RRule.js

Tags: javascript

I have an object array which looks like:

```
["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday"]
```

Is there a way to convert this to:

```
[Sunday,Monday,Tuesday]
```

That is, just remove the apostrophes. I read at some places that the JSON.parse() method could work, but never found an answer that worked. Also I am new to this, so I'd appreciate if you could type the code snippet as the answer along with the explanation.

Thank you!

**UPDATE**
I apologize if the above didn't make sense, here is the full explanation.
I have 7 checkboxes through which I get the days of the weeks that the user clicks on.
I am trying to implement the recurring events using RRULE.js ([See link](https://jakubroztocil.github.io/rrule/))

I also executed

```
console.log(typeof(selected_days));
```

And it logged OBJECT not STRING.
If you know about RRule.js, I want to pass the days selected from the checkboxes to the 'byweekday' property.
For reference, this is what a typical RRule.js rule looks like:

```
 rule = new RRule({
  freq: RRule.WEEKLY,
  count: 30,
  interval: 1,
  byweekday: [RRule.MO, RRule.TU, RRule.WE, RRule.TH, RRule.FR, RRule.SA, RRule.SU]
})
```

The only problem is when I pass my array in the 'byweekday' property, it returns an error saying

> weekday undefined

This is why I want to update my array which looks like:

```
["RRule.SU", "RRule.MO", "RRule.TU", "RRule.WE", "RRule.TH", "RRule.FR", "RRule.SA"]
```

into something that can be readableby RRule.js:

```
[RRule.MO, RRule.TU, RRule.WE, RRule.TH, RRule.FR, RRule.SA, RRule.SU]
```

I hope this clarified my question.

**UPDATE**
Here is the code as requested:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function saveRule() {
        //Create an Array.
        var selected = new Array();
        var selected_days = document.getElementById("days");
        //Reference all the CheckBoxes in Table.
        var chks = selected_days.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
        // Loop and push the checked CheckBox value in Array.
        for (var i = 0; i < chks.length; i++) {
            if (chks[i].checked) {
                selected.push(chks[i].value);
            }
        }
        //Display the selected CheckBox values.
        if (selected.length > 0) {
            console.log("Selected values: " + selected.join(","));
        }
        var getFreqType = document.querySelector('input[name="frequencytype"]:checked');        
        console.log(getFreqType.value)

        var getInterval = document.querySelector('input[name="interval"]');        
        console.log(getInterval.value)

        /**
         * !RRULE BELOW
         * */
        console.log("Rubadubadoooo")
        console.log(typeof(selected));
        console.log(selected);
        console.log(getFreqType.value);
        console.log(getInterval.value);   
        const selected_object = JSON.toString(selected);
        console.log(selected_object);
        console.log("RRULE is going ot be displayed below");
        const RRule = rrule.RRule;

        const rule = new RRule({
            freq: RRule.WEEKLY  ,
            interval: getInterval.value,
            count: 5,
            byweekday: selected,
            //dtstart: new Date(Date.UTC(2021, 1, 1, 10, 30)),
            //until: new Date(Date.UTC(2020, 12, 31))
        });

        console.log(rule.toString());
        console.log(rule.all().length)
    }

        
    
</script>
```

Comment: `[RRule.MO, RRule.TU, RRule.WE, RRule.TH, RRule.FR, RRule.SA, RRule.SU]` not valid js array. Without quotes `RRule.MO` will refer to some variable

Comment: Quotes are not part of the data, they're just the way strings literals are written in source code and encoded in JSON. `JSON.stringify()` adds them, `JSON.parse()` removes them.

Comment: @brk could you explain further? I know its not a valid array but as you see it in the RRule.js rule statement, that is how the list of days is accepted. I want to pass my array the value to the "byweekdays" property of the rule

Comment: @Barmar if possible could you give the code snippet for your solution? I am new to JavaScript

Comment: There's no `weekday` in your code, I don't see how it could be getting that error.

Comment: Please post the code that's getting that error.

Comment: @Barmar I've added it, please see the last update. And it is not a 'ERROR' per say but when I console my RRule statement, it gives me BYDAY: undefined,undefined instead of something like BYDAY: RRule.MO, RRule.TU

Comment: `RRule.MO` is a variable. When you write `[RRule.MO]`, it puts the value of the variable into the array, not the name of the variable.

Comment: You can also use numbers in that array: 0 = Monday, 1 = Tuesday, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the solution to my problem, based on what @Barmer said.
The JSON. operations didn't work.
I implemented switch statements and made integer arrays which I further passed as variables to the properties of RRule.js

Here is the solution I implemented.
Thanks to all, cheers!

```
for (var i = 0; i < chks.length; i++) {
        if (chks[i].checked) {
            selected.push(chks[i].value);
            rule_array.push(i);
            var chosen_day = chks[i].value;
            switch (chosen_day) {
                case 'RRule.MO':
                    array_rule.push(0);
                    break;
                case 'RRule.TU':
                    array_rule.push(1);
                    break;
                case 'RRule.WE':
                    array_rule.push(2);
                    break;
                case 'RRule.TH':
                    array_rule.push(3);
                    break;
                case 'RRule.FR':
                    array_rule.push(4);
                    break;
                case 'RRule.SA':
                    array_rule.push(5);
                    break;
                case 'RRule.SU':
                    array_rule.push(6);
                    break;
                default:
                    console.log("Please choose a day");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }


const rule = new RRule({
            freq: freq_type,
            interval: getInterval.value,
            wkst: RRule.SU,
            count: 5,
            byweekday: array_rule,
            //dtstart: new Date(Date.UTC(2021, 1, 1, 10, 30)),
            //until: new Date(Date.UTC(2020, 12, 31))
        });
```